# Display JSON arrays in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, json, html

so I received the following array from another student and my job is to display it in the HTML.

I've followed examples found on here as well as other sites. It's my first attempt at doing this.

Anyway, I've called in the required values, but they're not displaying. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

This is the script block and I'll attach some of the HTML. Currently the json is situated before the closing head tag.

```
 <script>

      var height = {"height" : "1.76m"};
      var weight = {"weight" : "65kg"};
      var bmi = {weight/(height*height)};
      var cholesterol = {"cholesterol" : "26mmol/d"};
      var glucose ={"glucose" : "100mg/dl"};
      var pressure = {"pressure" : "120/80"};
      var pulseRate = {"pulse rate" : "80bpm"};

      window.onload = function() {

        obj = JSON.parse(height, weight, bmi, cholesterol, glucose, pressure, pulseRate);

        document.getElementById("hgt").innerHTML = obj.height[1];
        document.getElementById("wgt").innerHTML = obj.weight[1];
        document.getElementById("bmi").innerHTML = obj.bmi[1];
        document.getElementById("chol").innerHTML = obj.cholesterol[1];
        document.getElementById("gluc").innerHTML = obj.glucose[1];
        document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML = obj.pressure[1];
        document.getElementById("rpr").innerHTML = obj.pulseRate[1];

      };

 </script>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h3 class="heading">Today</h3>
        <img class="picture2" src="images/icon-height.png" />
      <div class="caption">
       <h2 id="hgt"></h2>
       <p>height</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is no JSON here - only objects. So no need to parse them. Also look up the actual parameters of JSON.parse(). Furthermore the bmi  object is missing a doublepoint.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is by definition a string. all other types are just what they are. you could convert a JSON to an object by parsing it or make one with stringify.

Comment: I was just trying to define the variables you defined, and I'm getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /`. The error came from line 3. So your script is crashing at line `var bmi = {weight/(height*height)};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variables `height`, `weight`... do not have to be parsed, since they are valid JSON Objects, you could save yourself some time by assigning `obj` like this:

```
var obj = {
   height: "1.76",
   weight: "65kg",
   ...,
   bmi: //your calculation here!
};

document.getElementById("yourid").innerHTML = obj.weight;
...
```

Since JSON objects use `key`:`value` pairs, you can simply access the values by using `object.key` or `object['key']`.

Since you're trying to access the values by using `obj.weight[1]` I'm guessing that you're trying to get the second value in `{ "weight" : "67kg" }`. But since this is a valid Object, `weight` is the key and `"67kg"` is the value. So you are trying to get the value at index 1 on an Object (`obj.weight[1]`). For this to work your object must have a key `1` or be an array. I hope you get what I'm trying to explain to you.

To make it a lot more simpler, you could just use `height.height` instead of the not working `obj.height[1]`, because your `var height` is an object with a key `height`. But for readability I would suggest the format from my snippet.

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: No problem, just to make sure, you have a variable `pulseRate` and its set to `{ "pulse rate" : "80bpm" }`. In that case, the key is `"pulse rate"` with a space, so you wont be able to do this: `var obj = { pulse rate: "80bpm", weight: "65kg" }`, you would have to remove the space in the name to avoid errors. Just change it to `pulserate` or something like that if you want to use it this way: `obj.pulserate`